# How to restrict calculated value to four decimal places

Tags: c#

I want to limit decimal place till 4 for below code, how to do that,

```
var a = Convert.ToDecimal( 80794992640) / (1024 * 1024);
```

Comment: presentation and representation are different concerns....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can round it if you want to fix it to 4 digits:

```
var a = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal( 80794992640) / (1024 * 1024),4 );
```

but if your concern is to restrict it in the display then you can just apply the restriction in the `ToString` method:

```
a.ToString("0.####");
```

the latter method will keep the precision for the calculations but cut the precision only for display

Answer (score 0):

This will round it to 4 decimal places:

```
var a = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal( 80794992640) / (1024 * 1024), 4);
```